# json response errors check on php

Tags: php, json

[true json url](https://tr.api.pvp.net/api/lol/tr/v1.4/summoner/by-name/rapertuar?api_key=RGAPI-2F65B634-F9C5-4DA7-A5E3-1D955D5D1E3B)

```
$url = 'https://tr.api.pvp.net/api/lol/tr/v1.4/summoner/by-name/r2aper1tuar?api_key=RGAPI-2F65B634-F9C5-4DA7-A5E3-1D955D5D1E3B';
$content = file_get_contents($url);
$json = json_decode($content);
```

These codes work but if JSON url is not true. It will show error on index.php
How can i check these error.

[not true json](https://tr.api.pvp.net/api/lol/tr/v1.4/summoner/by-name/rap5er3tu1ar?api_key=RGAPI-2F65B634-F9C5-4DA7-A5E3-1D955D5D1E3B)

if i use "not true JSON" , I take this error.

```
{
"status": {
    "message": "Not Found",
    "status_code": 404
    }
}
```

Now how to check errors ?

Comment: use json_decode() here, and get the value from property

Comment: you also receive a 404 header from second url, so you can check for that! (that's what it is sent for...)

Answer (score 0):

Check the response:

```
if( property_exists ( $json , "status" ) )
{
    $status_code = $json -> status -> status_code;
    $message = $json -> status -> message;

    // do something...
}
```

Comment: what do you intend by "does not work"?? what's the output? what error so you get?